# Python converting bytes to hex and back

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I have a long hex string that looks like so: `"fffffffffffffffff..."`. It is part of a processed bitmap image (ppm format). I convert the string to a usable list of numbers, like: `[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255...]`(and I later extract RGB values from it), however I am unable to convert the numbers back to this hex string properly.

```
raw_hex = "fffffffffffffffffff..." # a long string taken from a file
list_of_ints = [int(raw_hex[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(raw_hex), 2)] # a list of ints, looks like [255,255,255...]
```

I then attempt to reverse the process by doing the following command (I want to obtain `raw_hex` again from `list_of_ints`:

```
reversed_hex = ''.join([format(int(i), 'x') for i in data])
```

This appears to provide a similar output (`"ffffffffffffffffff..."`). However I can tell that they are not the same, as running `len(raw_hex)` and `len(reversed_hex)`, produces `1500000` and `1490871`. However I know the intermediate command is working properly, as `len(list_of_ints)` yields `750000`, which is what I expect. So what am I doing wrong, and how can I obtain the original hex string from the integer list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the image raw hex includes padded 0s? If that's the case, these padded 0s are being lost when converting from the ints back to hex. This can be fixed as follows:

```
reversed_hex = ''.join([format(int(i), '02x') for i in data])
```

Comment: You mean that his `''.join([format(int(i), 'x') for i in data])` does not provide a leading 0 for int value smaller then 16? good spot.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

There are convenience functions to convert from a hexadecimal string to bytes and back:

```py
>>> raw_hex = 'ffffffff'
>>> bytes.fromhex(raw_hex)
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> ints = list(bytes.fromhex(raw_hex))
>>> ints
[255, 255, 255, 255]
>>> bytes(ints)
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> bytes(ints).hex()
'ffffffff'
```